XSLT: How to check for duplicate entries and return only the entry that has active status (for that entry that has duplicate)?
I'm trying to output a text file that will remove a duplicate and only return the active one for that id that has duplicate. **Example if I have 2 entries in the xml but entries have same ID, only output the one with status active. While the others that dont have duplicates, just include in the output regardless if it's active or inactive.
For Example
<Report_Data>
    <Report_Entry>
        <id>1</id>
        <status>Inactive</status>
     </Report_Entry>
     <Report_Entry>
        <id>1</id>
        <status>Active</status>
     </Report_Entry>
     <Report_Entry>
        <id>3</id>
        <status>Active</status>
     </Report_Entry>
     <Report_Entry>
        <id>4</id>
        <status>Inactive</status>
     </Report_Entry>
 </Report_Data>

I tried to use xsl:for-each-group and group-by but not achieving the result.
<xsl:template match="Report_Data">
    <row>
        <text>id|status</text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
    </row>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="Report_Entry" group-by="id[../status='Active']">
        <row>
            <id>
                <xsl:value-of select="id"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
            </id>
            <status>
                <xsl:value-of select="status"/>
             </status>
        </row>

The output is:
id|status
1|Active
3|Active

But the desired output is
id|status
1|Active
3|Active
4|Inactive

Tried this code but also returning the incorrect output
<xsl:for-each-group select="Report_Entry[status='Active']" group-by="id">

Thanks in advance. :)

Your title says "return only the id that has active status" but your output includes "4|Inactive". Please explain in more detail the logic you want to apply here.

Also please edit your input to be a well-formed XML document.

@michael.hor257k edited thanks

Your input is still not well-formed, QnA

sorry, updated thanks

It's still not well-formed. I'm going to fix it

It's always a good idea to provide sample data and to test that sample data with your own code.

hi @ConalTuohy thanks for looking into this, but the input xml looks correct to me now, or can pinpoint what is missing? (not sure if its formatting here or what?) thanks. I am testing in oxygen with the xml data. thanks

I removed the wd: namespace prefix which appeared on the closing tags only of a couple of elements: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/79017067/revisions

yea i actually removed it also. hmm not sure what hapend but ya ok. thank you.

You missed a couple https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/79017067/4

My interpretation of your requirement would be:
<xsl:template match="/Report_Data">
    <xsl:text>id|status&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="Report_Entry" group-by="id">
        <xsl:value-of select="id"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="(current-group()[status='Active'], 
                               current-group()[status='Inactive'])[1]/status"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>


Your question is not very clear. Maybe something like this could work for you:
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/Report_Data">
    <xsl:text>id|status&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="Report_Entry" group-by="id">
        <xsl:value-of select="id"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="if(current-group()/status='Active') then 'Active' else 'Inactive'"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>


Thank you for your response. Updated the question and description btw

Your question is still not clear. If you have a case where this answer does not produce the expected result, please add it your question and explain.

hi @y.arazim thanks for the code but ya does not produce the expected result.... ... the output is all the ids are included regardless if it's active or inactive.. Except if the id has duplicate, only output the id that has active status.  **as Example above ( the entry with id 1), I have 2 entries for id 1 in the xml, only output the id 1 with status active. While the others that dont have duplicates (id 3 & 4), just include in the output regardless if it's active or inactive. thank you.

My code DOES produce the expected result shown in your question.

Yes y.arazim's code produces the correct result when I run it; the exact same result as Michael Kay's answer below: three rows with ids 1 and 3 both Active and then row 4 is Inactive

hi y.arazim looks like this works now. thanks again.

It worked all the time. I haven't changed anything.

Late to the party, I know, but here's yet another very similar option.
This one first sorts the Report_Entry elements by status into a variable, and then groups the entries in that variable. Pre-sorting ensures that the  context node inside each iteration of the xsl:for-each-group has an Active status (inside an xsl:for-each-group, the context node is the first item in its group).
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/Report_Data">
    <xsl:text>id|status&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:variable name="sorted-entries">
      <xsl:for-each select="Report_Entry">
        <xsl:sort select="status"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="$sorted-entries/Report_Entry" group-by="id">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(id, '|', status, '&#10;')"/>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

